# Base of matrices

Tags: matrices

> Show that this set of matrices $$ \mathcal{B}:=\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\Bigg\} $$ builds a base of $ \mathbb{R}^{2,2} $.

At first I want to show that these matrices are a generator for $ \mathbb{R}^{2,2} $. For this purpose I look at this matrix $ \begin{pmatrix}t_1 & t_2 \\t_3 & t_4 \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{2,2} $ and I try to solve this equation:

$$ a\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+b\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+c\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+d\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t_1 & t_2 \\t_3 & t_4 \end{pmatrix}\\ \Leftrightarrow \left(\begin{array}{ll|ll}{a} & {b} & {t_{1}} & {t_{2}} \\ {c} & {d} & {t_{3}} & {t_{4}}\end{array}\right) $$

Using the gaussian algorithm leeds to this result:

$$ \left(\begin{array}{ll|ll}{1} & {0} & \frac{t_1(ad-bc)-b(t_3a-t_1c)}{a(ad-bc)} & \frac{t_2(ad-bc)-b(t_4a-t_2c)}{a(ad-bc)} \\ {0} & {1} & \frac{t_3a-t_1c}{ad-bc} & \frac{t_4a-t_2c}{ad-bc}\end{array}\right) $$

Now I'm confused. How can I handle the two cases: $ ad-bc=0 $ and $ a(ad-bc)=0 $?

Comment: To show that your set spans the space, it suffices to remark that $a = t_1, \dots, d = t_4$ is a solution to your system of equations.  To show that your set is linearly independent, it suffices to note that the only solution in the case of $t_1 = \dots = t_4 = 0$ is $a = \cdots = d = 0$.

Comment: There is no reason to use the Gaussian algorithm for this question

Comment: Also, the way in which you have set up your augmented matrix is not appropriate for your system of equations.

Comment: This sounds for me to generalized. Why I cannot solve it like my way?

Comment: So far I was used to solve those problems with this algorithm if I had to show that for example $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} $ generates the vectorspace $ 
\mathbb{R^3} $. What is/are the difference(s) to the case from above?

Comment: Here's a concrete difference between how you applied the algorithm: in your example, you would probably end up row reducing a matrix of $3$ vectors (or you would have $3$ vectors on the left side of the augmented matrix).  In your case, you only have two vectors on the left side but $4$ elements in the base.

Comment: I'll write up a more detailed answer that addresses how one would apply your algorithm to a more complicated example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the approach I recommend is as follows. To show that your set spans the space, it suffices to remark that $a = t_1, \dots, d = t_4$ is a solution to your system of equations. To show that your set is linearly independent, it suffices to note that the only solution in the case of $t_1 = \cdots = t_4 = 0$ is $a = \cdots = d = 0$.

---

First of all, if you **are** going to apply you algorithm, note that the key thing is not the shape of the matrices in the base, but the resulting system of equations.  For instance, consider the example
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
given in the comments.

First of all, it suffices to show that these matrices are linearly independent, which can be done more easily using Gaussian elimination.  But sticking to doing things your way, we want to show that the equation
$$
a \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix} +  b\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} = \pmatrix{t_1\\t_2\\t_3}
$$
always has a solution.  Since two matrices (column-vectors in this case) are equal if and only if their entries are the same, we end up with $3$ equations:
$$
a + c = t_1,\\
a + b = t_2,\\
b + c = t_3.
$$
The augmented matrix for this system is given by
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&1&t_1\\1&1&0&t_2\\0&1&1&t_3
\end{array}\right].
$$
It so happens that when the elements in question are column-vectors, the columns of the augmented matrices are precisely the columns of your base. If we apply this to your system of equations, then we really have
$$
a\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+b\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+c\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+d\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t_1 & t_2 \\t_3 & t_4 \end{pmatrix}\\
\iff
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&0&0&t_1\\
0&1&0&0&t_2\\
0&0&1&0&t_3\\
0&0&0&1&t_4
\end{array}\right].
$$
As the algorithm goes, there is nothing to do.  For your more complicated problem, we would find that
$$
a\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\1&0 \end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\-3&0 \end{pmatrix} + d\begin{pmatrix} 0&3\\0&1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} t_1&t_2\\t_3&t_4 \end{pmatrix}\\ 
\iff
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&1&0&0&t_1\\
1&0&0&3&t_2\\
0&1&-3&0&t_3\\
0&0&0&1&t_4
\end{array}\right].
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} +
c\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} +
d\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}t_1 & t_2 \\t_3 & t_4 \end{pmatrix}$$ if and only if $a = t_1$, $b = t_2$, $c = t_3$ and $d = t_4$.

Comment: Ok. But how I have to proceed if my base is made of "more complicated" matrices? Like this:$ \mathcal{B}:=\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\-3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 3 \\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\Bigg\} $

Comment: Proceed in the same fashion :
$$a\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\1&0 \end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\-3&0 \end{pmatrix} + d\begin{pmatrix} 0&3\\0&1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} t_1&t_2\\t_3&t_4 \end{pmatrix},$$
that is,
$$\begin{pmatrix} a+b&a+3d\\b-3c&d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} t_1&t_2\\t_3&t_4 \end{pmatrix}$$
and just solve the system of equations for $a,b,c$ and $d$.